# Using reverse in lambda function

Tags: haskell

I'm new with Haskell and came to this problem. I'm using
`gio = \x -> x == reverse (x)` which returns error saying `ERROR C:\Users\Gbaramidze\Desktop\gio.hs:18 - Unresolved top-level overloading` Can't figure out why. Hope you can help.

**P.S.:**
I provided a signature as you instructed but it didn't work. I got an error:

```
- Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : gio
*** Type          : [a] -> Bool
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Eq a
```

I'm using Hugs because that is the tool we use in university. The code I use is above, I have it in an .hs file and open it using Hugs.

Comment: Since you're new with Haskell can you possibly misstate the problem? It would be helpful if you rendered a minimal example and posted its code here... probably.

Comment: Add a type signature `gif :: [a] -> Bool`. Also, unless you have a _really_ good reason, stop using Hugs. It has not been supported for a while. GHC is the current go to compiler for Haskell.

Comment: Ack. My edit window is closed, but you of course need the `Eq a` constraint.  `gif :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `(==)`, you must constrain the function to only work on types that support this operation. The correct type signature looks like this:

```
gio :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
gio = \x -> x == reverse x
```